# Temperature converter android app

Tags: java, android, button, radio-button

Here is my code and i'm not sure why the calculate button isn't working. It has to do with my onclick method but i'm not sure why its not working. My app closes when I try to open it. I'll include my logcat if needed. I'm pretty sure its something easy to fix since i'm almost done with this app.

```
package com.example.temperatureconverter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;


public class Calculate extends Activity 
{
private EditText in, out;
private RadioButton rd1, rd2;
private Button btn1;
DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("#.##");

//******************onCreate()*****************************
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle b) 
{
    super.onCreate(b);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculate);

    in = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input);
    out =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.results);
    rd1 =(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
    rd2 =(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio2);
    btn1 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
}

//******************buttonClick()**********************
public void buttonClick(View v)
{
    double num = 0;
    switch(v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.radio1:
            if(rd1.isChecked())
            {
                rd1.setChecked(true);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.radio2:
            if(rd2.isChecked())
            {
                rd2.setChecked(true);
            }
            break;  
        case R.id.btn1:
            if(rd1.isChecked() == true)
            {
                num = Double.parseDouble(in.getText().toString());
                out.setText(String.valueOf(f.format(CelToF(num))));
            }
            else
            {
                num = Double.parseDouble(in.getText().toString());
                out.setText(String.valueOf(f.format(fToC(num))));
            }   
    }
}
//*****************CelToF()*****************************
public double CelToF(double num)
{
    return (9.0/5.0) * num + 32;
}

//*******************fToc()****************************
public double fToC(double num)
{
    return (num - 32) * 5.0/9.0;
}
}
```

here is my log cat

10-03 21:11:05.355: D/(2726): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb91314c0, tid 2726
10-03 21:11:05.425: W/EGL_emulation(2726): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
10-03 21:11:05.435: D/OpenGLRenderer(2726): Enabling debug mode 0
10-03 21:11:05.605: D/dalvikvm(2726): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 57K, 4% free 3327K/3448K, paused 42ms, total 45ms
10-03 21:11:10.025: D/AndroidRuntime(2726): Shutting down VM
10-03 21:11:10.035: W/dalvikvm(2726): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xadb03ba8)
10-03 21:11:10.115: E/AndroidRuntime(2726): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-03 21:11:10.115: E/AndroidRuntime(2726): Process: com.example.temperatureconverter, PID: 2726
10-03 21:11:10.115: E/AndroidRuntime(2726): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
10-03 21:11:10.115: E/AndroidRuntime(2726):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
10-03 21:11:10.115: E/AndroidRuntime(2726):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
10-03 21:11:10.115: E/AndroidRuntime(2726):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
10-03 21:11:10.115: E/AndroidRuntime(2726):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
10-03 21:11:10.115: E/AndroidRuntime(2726):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-03 21:11:10.115: E/AndroidRuntime(2726):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-03 21:11:10.115: E/AndroidRuntime(2726):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
10-03 21:11:10.115: E/AndroidRuntime(2726):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-03 21:11:10.115: E/AndroidRuntime(2726):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-03 21:11:10.115: E/AndroidRuntime(2726):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
10-03 21:11:10.115: E/AndroidRuntime(2726):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
10-03 21:11:10.115: E/AndroidRuntime(2726):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-03 21:11:10.115: E/AndroidRuntime(2726): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10-03 21:11:10.115: E/AndroidRuntime(2726):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-03 21:11:10.115: E/AndroidRuntime(2726):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-03 21:11:10.115: E/AndroidRuntime(2726):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
10-03 21:11:10.115: E/AndroidRuntime(2726):     ... 11 more
10-03 21:11:10.115: E/AndroidRuntime(2726): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.widget.RadioButton
10-03 21:11:10.115: E/AndroidRuntime(2726):     at com.example.temperatureconverter.Calculate.buttonClick(Calculate.java:55)
10-03 21:11:10.115: E/AndroidRuntime(2726):     ... 14 more

Comment: Try removing the .toSrings in your parseDouble.

Comment: Please post the stacktrace.

Comment: "I'll include my logcat if needed." it is always most helpful when your app crashes. Also, it is always a good idea to wrap parsing code in a `try/catch`.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your `num` on your onCreate with a value instead of trying to parse a nonexistent value from your text view.

So, instead of this:

```
num = Double.parseDouble(in.getText().toString());
```

Just do:

```
num = 0;
```

Or, if you don't want zero to be an initial value, just don't initialize it. And let num be properly populated after the onClick.

Also you don't need to manually uncheck your checkboxes, android does this for you if you wrap them inside a [RadioGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html)

Comment: Wait...are you saying he should use some arbitrary value for his variable instead of the one he needs? I also missed where he is unchecking *any* boxes. Checkboxes typically shouldn't be in a `RadioGroup` because that is not how a user would expect them to work

Comment: Not at all, I'm just pointing that he is not initializing properly his value. In fact, the initialization there is not needed at all, since he doesn't use num until the user actually clicks the button.

Comment: Ok, I missed it in `onCreate()`. I thought you were referring to where it is done in `onClick()`